# How to edit already annotated images (rectangular bounding box)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, object-detection, image-annotations

I have a CSV containing xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax of the box. Now I want a tool by which I can edit the annotation I have already done. If someone can suggest an open source tool or python script which can help achieve the same.
[image]

Example
I want to make the box broader in the following case. Only making the box broader is not the case. i want to be able to flexibly change the annotations.
[image]

Comment: I can't make sense of your question. Can you explain ?

Comment: Basically I have annotated the images manually sometime back. But now I want to change the annotation boundaries. I am looking for a tool or script to do that.

Comment: "change the annotation boundaries" ??

Comment: See the example

Comment: Are the annotations destructive overlay ?